# Character names with paste in summarise dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

i would like to know if it is possible to write a (character) name with e.g. paste in dplyr::summarise?

For example:

```
i <- "name"

# first working
iris %>%
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>%
  summarise(Sum_name = sum(Sepal.Length))

# second working
iris %>%
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>%
  summarise("Sum_name" = sum(Sepal.Length))

# third not working
iris %>%
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>%
  summarise(paste0("Sum_", i) = sum(Sepal.Length))
```

Is it possible to write something like the third example with paste?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `summarise(!!paste0("Sum_", i) := sum(Sepal.Length))` should work

Comment: Perfect and simple, obviously it does! Thank you very much for the fast help. Unfortunately i didn't saw the other thread before!